# `sudo adduser username admin` leads to `adduser: The group `admin' does not exist.`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to add a user to the sudoers file with the simple command

```
sudo adduser username admin
```

but I get `adduser: The group 'admin' does not exist`. So I checked out the sudoers file (`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers`), which contains among others, this line:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

which as far as I know means that the admin group exists.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complaint about "admin" being nonexistant is unrelated to what's in the sudoers file. It is referring to [usergroup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_groups#Group_management), as listed in `/etc/group`.

**To create a group named admin**, type `sudo groupadd admin`. After that, your command as listed should function as intended. You of course only need to create the admin group once.

**To add an existing user to the admin group:**

`usermod -a -G admin username` (personally I like to just edit /etc/group, bet that's probably frowned upon. I've been doing it for decades and don't care about frowns).

For more info: `man group` and `man usermod`

Answer (score 1):

You created a new user with the username `username`    NOT what you appear to have syntax would be :

```
sudo useradd admin

sudo usermod {Some Options}  admin
```

// second command changes the defaults (/home/USERNAME, passwd,etc) which unless declared otherwise in previous command will